Migrated site is showing unsafe to visitors weeks after installing new SSL
I recently migrated my church's website from a platform called churchco to my siteground servers. I installed a new SSL cert from Let's Encrypt. For users that have been to the site before google is showing the unsafe page. once you proceed however that message does not come back. I would normally probably just let it be but the older members of our congregation are refusing to proceed. Is there any way to fix this? I am assuming the problem is the old cert being cached for these users but it has been weeks and is still happening. I thought certs expired faster than that? is there a way to force the new cert onto users? https://bridgebc.org/
I don't know what to try, I thought for sure the old certs would expire and clear out but that does not seem to be happening.

This is not a programming question so it's not on topic here, maybe a better fit on Webmasters. But even if it were somehow on-topic here, there are not enough details to do anything but guess. What exactly is the error message these users are receiving? There are different messages for different certificate problems. What happens when you tell these people to clear their cache? What browsers are they using? Believe me, I feel your pain, I run the website for my retirement organization, and there are some very old members.
